# SAM package throws Error: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Tags: devops, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, aws-devops

**Hello I need help with this. I'm new to this and please excuse me if I didn't ask the question properly its my first time doing so.
I am currently following this tutorial on AWS Code Deploy to Deploy a lambda function using AWS SAM and I came to this point where it says I should run this below**
Sam package 
--template-file template.yml 
--output-template-file package.yml 
--s3-bucket your-S3-bucket.

From running this
sam package 
--template-file template.yml 
--output-template-file package.yml 
--s3-bucket your-S3-bucket
It kept returning this message error below

WARNING: Your template includes a deployment configuration that will create an additional unecessary CodeDeploy Service Role.
By 9/25 the SAM service will no longer create this extra role, and any applications deployed after this date that
directly reference this role will produce an error as the role will be removed. For more information on this issue
and how to mitigate it, please read these docs[1]

[1] https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/wiki/08-2020-codeploy-servicerole

Error: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
Traceback:
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\cli_validation\image_repository_validation.py", line 92, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 184, in wrapped
raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 149, in wrapped
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 103, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\cli\main.py", line 95, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands_utils\cdk_support_decorators.py", line 39, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands_utils\command_exception_handler.py", line 88, in wrapper_command_exception_handler
raise ex
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands_utils\command_exception_handler.py", line 68, in wrapper_command_exception_handler
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\package\command.py", line 113, in cli
do_cli(
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\package\command.py", line 177, in do_cli
package_context.run()
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\package\package_context.py", line 123, in run
docker_client = docker.from_env()
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 96, in from_env
return cls(
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 45, in **init**
self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 197, in **init**
self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
raise DockerException(

An unexpected error was encountered while executing "sam package".
Search for an existing issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Bug%3A%20sam%20package%20-%20DockerException
Or create a bug report:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md&title=Bug%3A%20sam%20package%20-%20DockerException